# XmlHttpRequest sends blank data to php using POST method

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

I have attached the two files, I am trying to verify recaptcha from server side and trying to pass grecaptcha.repsonse() to php using XMLHttpRequest but it sends blank data using POST.I am able to get the solution for the same.

**Following code has the XMLHttpRequest**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sendAjaxRequest() {
        if (grecaptcha === undefined) {
            alert('Recaptcha not defined'); 
            return; 
        }

        var response = grecaptcha.getResponse();

        if (!response) {
            alert('Coud not get recaptcha response'); 
            return; 
        }

        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = 'validate-recaptcha.php';

        //Send the proper header information along with the request
        http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        temp = JSON.stringify(response);
        http.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
                alert(http.responseText);
            }
        }
        http.open('POST', url, true);
        http.send(response);
     }
</script>
```

**Following is the php code:**

```
<?php
if (empty($_POST['response'])) {
    exit('Please set recaptcha variable');
}
// validate recaptcha
$response = $_POST['recaptcha'];
$post = http_build_query(array (
    'response' => $response,
    'secret' => 'mysecretkey',
    'remoteip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
    )
);
$opts = array('http' => array (
    'method' => 'POST',
    'header' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'content' => $post
    )
 );
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$serverResponse = 
@file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify', false, $context);
if (!$serverResponse) {
    exit('Failed to validate Recaptcha');
}
$result = json_decode($serverResponse);
if (!$result -> success) {
    exit('Invalid Recaptcha');
}
exit('Recaptcha Validated');
?>
```

Comment: What is `response`?

Comment: whether the recaptcha has been ticked or not.

Comment: What is the precise value of `response`? A description of what it means isn't helpful.

Comment: During the script part im getting a huge string on ticking the recaptcha which i want to pass to php but it is going as blank.

Comment: What is the string? Is it `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`? You *claim* you are sending `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data, but we can't see it.

Comment: I am not sure whether it is application/x-www-form-urlencoded string or not

Comment: So look at it and find out. Or look at the documentation. Do you have any reason to expect it to be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`? I wouldn't have expected it to be in that format.

Comment: 03AHghOlxrM_ZC2PKUL3- JaBl19acV jgtsbDcjBAu4pSoGtLu$br 55BltMOyreGimsHKSoHp4oS1h HPECOVwn63tcroOSnOVwLAKeLSakvRELakbtovwccwmtap2yulUrHMrk48 OwVrokok36mi_Gfrpgxku2 HNGYKAfazilcyRvH T4mfx(94urG¢2ccnvioGmeR2m51Qw- 901BnBXG1RSYUm20G 046x)X0ADZXBUCK     such is the string!

Comment: So no, it isn't. You should encode it the way you said you would encode it.